# jquery Gallery multiple filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

hi guys i have downloaded this code from the weblink below which it lets me filter the gallery page that i have. But they do not have much documentation on the website regarding this on multiple filtering function? eg lets say i have 2 options Country and Type i can select US and Cars so it will show filtered by us and cars.

[Demo Link](http://jscraft.net/demo/plugins/filters/index.html)

This is the link of the coe that i have used.

can anyone help me on this ?

```
<div class="filters demo1">
    <div class="filter">
        <a href="#" rel="city">City</a>
        <a href="#" rel="cars">Cars</a>
        <a href="#" rel="other">Other</a>
        <a href="#" rel="all">All</a>
    </div>

    This is the part for filter option 2

    <div class="filter2">
        <a href="#" rel="Malaysia">Malaysia</a>
        <a href="#" rel="India">India</a>
        <a href="#" rel="US">US</a>
        <a href="#" rel="ALL">All</a>
    </div>

    <div class="filter3">
        <a href="#" rel="East">East</a>
        <a href="#" rel="West">West</a>
        <a href="#" rel="North">North</a>
        <a href="#" rel="ALL">All</a>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="cars">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="city">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="cars">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="city">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img7.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="cars">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="cars">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="city">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img8.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="cars">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="other">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img10.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="city">
                <a href="#"><img src="assets/img12.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

HTML CODE

```
 <div class="filters demo1">
        <div class="filter">
            <a href="#" rel="city">City</a>
            <a href="#" rel="cars">Cars</a>
            <a href="#" rel="other">Other</a>
            <a href="#" rel="all">All</a>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li class="cars">
                    <a href="#"><img src="assets/img1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </li>
                <li class="city">
                    <a href="#"><img src="assets/img6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </li>
                <li class="cars">
                    <a href="#"><img src="assets/img5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </li>
                <li class="city">
                    <a href="#"><img src="assets/img7.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </li>
                <li class="cars">
                    <a href="#"><img src="assets/img3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </li>
                <li class="cars">
                    <a href="#"><img src="assets/img4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </li>
                <li class="city">
                    <a href="#"><img src="assets/img8.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </li>
                <li class="cars">
                    <a href="#"><img src="assets/img2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </li>
                <li class="other">
                    <a href="#"><img src="assets/img10.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </li>
                <li class="city">
                    <a href="#"><img src="assets/img12.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
 $(function(){
     $('.filters.demo1').filters();
 });
```

Note: Don't forget to include jQuery and Filter plugin js file. Put jquery.js on top of filter plugin file

Comment: hi what i mean is not like that. Checkout my example on top with filter 1 2 and 3